# How can I solve a "module not found" error when running python scripts?

Tags: bash, scripts, python3, python-2.7

*Preface*

This is most likely a question which has been asked before but alas, none of those previous have been able to provide a conclusive answer/fix.

*Actual issue*

I'm trying to run a script which references to 2 distinct files referenced in the file run.

Run contains the following script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
  echo "This script must be run as root (e.g. sudo)"
  exit 1
else
  (odr-dabmux demo.mux |
  odr-dabmod -f /dev/stdout -g0 -m 1 -r 3200000 |
  python2 demo.py)
fi
```

Running the script gives me the following error which I've been trying to fix for a while now:

```
./run: line 7: odr-dabmux: command not found
./run: line 8: odr-dabmod: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 4, in <module>
    from gnuradio import blocks
ImportError: No module named gnuradio
```

At first I decided the line 7 & 8 error and decided to tackle `ImportError: No module named gnuradio`

So I went ahead and sudo apt installed gnuradio. gnuradio can now be found in

```
/usr/include/gnuradio
```

and as well as

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio
```

After getting the proper libraries, I ran it again but to no avail. I keep getting the `ImportError: No module named gnuradio`

Does anyone know what the issue here is?
Any help would be very much appreciated!

contents of demo.py for the curious:

```
# echo "Hello DAB" | nc -w0 -u 127.0.0.1 4321#!/usr/bin/env python2
# # pylint: disable=missing-docstring
 
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import gr
import osmosdr
 
 
SAMPLE_RATE = 3200000
BANDWIDTH = 1.75e6
 
 
class HackRFSink(gr.top_block):
 
def __init__(self):
    gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Hackrf Dab Sink")

    self.hackrf = osmosdr.sink(args="numchan=" + str(1) + " " + "hackrf=0")
    self.hackrf.set_sample_rate(SAMPLE_RATE)
    self.hackrf.set_center_freq(218.640e6, 0)
    self.hackrf.set_freq_corr(0, 0)
    self.hackrf.set_gain(14, 0)
    self.hackrf.set_if_gain(47, 0)
    self.hackrf.set_bb_gain(14, 0)
    self.hackrf.set_antenna("", 0)
    self.hackrf.set_bandwidth(BANDWIDTH, 0)
    # echo "Hello DAB" | nc -w0 -u 127.0.0.1 4321
    self.scaler = blocks.multiply_const_vcc((1, ))
    self.infile = blocks.file_source(
        gr.sizeof_gr_complex * 1,
        "/dev/stdin",
        False
    )

    self.connect((self.infile, 0), (self.scaler, 0))
    self.connect((self.scaler, 0), (self.hackrf, 0))



def main():
    transmitter = HackRFSink()
    transmitter.start()
    transmitter.wait()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if gr.enable_realtime_scheduling() != gr.RT_OK:
        print("Error: failed to enable real-time scheduling.")
    main()
```

edit: the errors with odr-dabmux and odr-odr-dabmod have been fixed in the meantime! Still having issues with the `ImportError: No module named gnuradio`

Comment: Your script runs `python2 demo.py` but you appear to have installed `gnuradio` for `python3`